# by specifying file extensions 'not file names', python code to download files from url

Tags: python, web

I tried several codes, this is the latest, to download any file has a CSV extension from a provided URL. It does download the file, however it is corrupted. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import os
import tarfile
import h5py
from tqdm import tqdm
import argparse
import pandas as pd

def download_main(
    url,
    save_path="/home/mohammed/spatialprot/store",
    file_format=None
):
    
    try:            
        # Send an HTTP GET request to the URL to retrieve the file content.
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True) #, params={"format": "csv"}
        response.raise_for_status()  # Check for any errors in the request
   
        # Open a local file for writing in binary mode.
        with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
            for chunk in tqdm(response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192)):
                if chunk:  # Filter out keep-alive new chunks.
                    file.write(chunk)

        print(f"Downloaded {url}, saved to {save_path}")
        csv = pd.read_csv(save_path)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: For testable code, try to also include your imports. 
But for the question, what does "corrupted" mean?

Comment: Unless the url is private, please share it

Comment: https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/mpjzbtfgfr/1
this is the link and there is a csv file in there, when it is downloaded it shows things i do not understand but not what the file actually contains

Comment: @MohammedZidane That code will download an HTML page - not a CSV file

Comment: okay, how to make it download the csv file in the page? i almost have no clue fromt this point

Comment: It sounds vaguely like what you are trying to do is download the HTML from that URL, parsing it to find the link to the actual CSV file, and then downloading that also. Is the "corrupted" file actually the HTML source of the page you linked to in a comment? Please [edit] your question to clarify these things (but ultimately, the code you posted does exactly what you want if you give it a valid URL to an actual CSV file).

Comment: (Also, seems that the HTML source for that page doesn't actually contain the CSV link; it is presumably hidden behind some fugly Javascript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the HTML document, you'll see that the downloadable files are in a ZIP file. Actually, there's only one file in the zip in this case. You can access it like this:

```
import requests
import zipfile
import tempfile

URL = "https://prod-dcd-datasets-cache-zipfiles.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mpjzbtfgfr-1.zip"
CHUNK = 32 * 1024

with requests.get(URL, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as outdata:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK):
            outdata.write(chunk)
        outdata.flush()
        with zipfile.ZipFile(outdata) as zip:
            print("Extracting", zip.namelist())
            zip.extractall()
```

The extracted file (CRC_clusters_neighborhoods_markers.csv) will be in your current working directory

Comment: @MohammedZidane I examined the HTML that your URL produces (by opening it in Safari) and then examined the content using standard Safari development tools. That led me to the "Download all" button and the underlying path to the ZIP file